# Use javascript to determine if an ASP.NET page is a postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is it possible to determine if an ASP.NET page is a postback from javascript?
So basically a javascript equivalent of C# Page.IsPostBack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would just put a render tag in the javascript

```
var isPostBack = <%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>;
```

Putting the "true" and "false" as strings should be done to eliminate any possible issues converting the type to a string as in C# true.ToString() is usually "True" which is an error in javascript.

Comment: This is something we do as well, very handy +1

Comment: Of course, at this point, it is technically "wasPostBack". :P

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Just use your server code to write out a javascript flag, if you really need this.

But I suspect you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you are trying to do but you might want to look into the PageRequestManagerClass:

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/PageRequestManagerClass/default.aspx

It exposes events for all different parts of the request.