# if not postback javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, equivalent

In [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) we have [**`IsPostBack`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that we use to validate if is or isn't a postback.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // Validate initially to force asterisks
    // to appear before the first roundtrip.
    Validate();
}
```

There is a javascript/jQuery equivalent?

### Note that

I don't wanna a solution using any other language than javascript (not excluding html, since it is not a programming language). Those questions below show how to do it using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), I don't wanna that!. I want a solution **in** javascript (or jQuery) **ONLY**.

- [How can I check for IsPostBack in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719/how-can-i-check-for-ispostback-in-javascript)
- [Use javascript to determine if an ASP.NET page is a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407237/use-javascript-to-determine-if-an-asp-net-page-is-a-postback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no direct equivalent. You'd have to track the state of the application using JavaScript. One popular way of doing that is hashbang urls. Ex:

http://domain.com/#some-state or http://domain.com/#/some-state

[window.location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) exposes the hashbang url and there are frameworks like AngularJS that make working with hashbang urls to control state and what view is displayed very easy.